# How do I use sed to find a possible asterisk [*]? in a string?

Tags: git, bash, sed

I am trying to write a sed command so it replaces a possible asterisk at the beginning of a string (it's for renaming a bunch of git branches at the same time).

My `git branch` returns lines similar to these:

```
  old-12345
* old-23456
  old-34567
  master
```

I want sed to output each line of the above output that has old as:

```
new-12345
new-23456
new-34567
```

I assumed one of the following would work:

```
$ echo "* old-12345" | sed 's/\*?\s*old-\(\d*\)/new-\1/'
$ echo "* old-12345" | sed 's/[*]?\s*old-\(\d*\)/new-\1/'
```

but sadly it did nothing. I want to have `\*?` or `[*]?` since `git branch` only puts the `*` next to the branch I am currently on. Why isn't the `?` working as I expect?

Comment: Do you want to remove `*` and replace **all** `old` by `new`?

Comment: yes. i want to remove `*` if it is there, all the spaces before old, and `old`, and replace all of that with `new`

Comment: use `git for-each-ref` instead of `git branch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
echo "* old-12345" | sed 's/.*old-\(\d*\)/new-\1/'
```

Comment: this works and i feel like an idiot for over complicating it. thanks! im still dumbfounded about why my solution didn't do anything though.

Comment: it's because the `?` doesn't work in your sed version, you need to use "extended regular expressions" which includes `?` , it comes with -r option

Comment: @krisharmas by changing your code like below it will work fine for me echo "* old-12345" | sed 's/\*\s\+old-\(\d*\)/new-\1/' though I am not sure why we need to add escape sequence for '+'

Comment: sigh. im on a mac. -r option isnt available in my version of sed. maybe i should try to update it. there is a -E option but it seems like it is only half working. thanks!